# Car charger for a laptop

Tags: laptop, charging

I have a laptop that has a charger that outputs 19.5V 7.7A. I want to be able to charge it in a car. One solution is to use an inverter in the car that takes that car's 12-15V DC and inverts it to 110 AC and then plug the laptop's charger into it and convert it to 19V DC. This seems to be super inefficient and a lot more equipment than I want to carry around.

Question: If I managed to find compatible connectors can I plug the car's 12V DC directly into a laptop that requires a higher voltage like 19V 7.7A? What is the impact of this?

Edits for more clarity:

- The laptop model is the [MSI GS60](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GS60-2PC-Ghost.html#hero-overview)
- I plan on using the charger in Taxis like Uber which is why I don't want to carry a heavy inverter. Not planning on using it in my own car.

Comment: It's all about the amps, but you still need the same voltage,

Comment: something like this? http://amzn.to/1EJJrzD

Comment: There are voltage converters for laptops that can step up the voltage to 19V but they are more suited to lower power devices and are typically only rated at about 100W maximum. Additionally an average car might struggle to provide the full 150W through the cigarette lighter even with the engine running and there would be extra power loss due to the step up adapter. If your laptop is put under heavy stress and draws more power than the adapter or car is designed for then you will probably blow a fuse or worse you could damage something.

Comment: I've had a 3kW 12v~ 240V inverter in my car for years. It lives in the boot [trunk] with mains extension sockets run back into the main interior, front & rear - saves buying 12v adaptors for everything I need to carry on the road - & can even be used to boil a kettle ;)

Comment: The title doesn't really describe your question well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can! They make automotive compatible chargers for most laptops because they are portable.

[image]

You didn't say what brand and model you have, but all you need to do is find one that is compatible. An Internet search will result in all kinds of adapters to choose from. 
[image]

*Note: images are for reference only, not a purchasing recommendation.*

Comment: Note that OP's AC adapter is for 7.7 A / 150 W - significantly more power than either of the ones you found can deliver. If he plugs his laptop into either of those (assuming they have the same plug, voltage, and polarity), there may be bad consequences.

Comment: Have used the Lenovo car adapter for my laptop for several years.  Works great and well worth the investment

Comment: @random832 those are just examples. As the answer says, "find one that is compatible". Please read the whole thing before correcting people's posts. :-)

Comment: @CharlieRB I was pointing out the low odds that one exists. I couldn't find one.

Comment: Some are model specific. Check the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: I search the manufacturer’s web site (MSI) but they don't list any car chargers.

Comment: Some searching on Amazon shows up this one: http://www.amazon.com/Charger-Stealth-MS-16GA-MS-16GC-MS-1756/dp/B00H4ILXIY/ however it seems to fall short by 30 W as its output is 19V 120 W. Is that extra 30W important?

Comment: [This one](http://www.amazon.com/GPK-Systems%C2%AE-Adapter-Notebook-Stealth/dp/B00KXF1YN4) is 150W and specifically lists being rated for your laptop.

Comment: Umm, your last link points at an AC adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a suitable car adaptor which will convert the voltage (most laptops need more than 12V) and protect the laptop from the spikes that are seen on a cars electrical system.

Anything that looks like a simple cable isn't going to be up to the job. You should expect a lump of comparable size to your laptop's AC adapter.

Unfortunately your laptop power supply has a rating of about 150W. It seems car adaptors that big aren't readilly available. I found a HP one http://www.allcarchargers.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=382 that matches your voltage and current requirements but I don't know if the connector is right.

Comment: Do you probably remember which one that was? I'm in a great need of one the OP was after with the same requirements for my HP laptop and anything I find is max 90W..